# Save a vector file in Matlab and put in array in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I saved a file in Matlab with a vector information:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
```

[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lxq66hlo9p37ad2/test.mat?dl=0)https://www.dropbox.com/s/lxq66hlo9p37ad2/test.mat?dl=0

How can I read this file in Python in order to get the same vector x in an array?

I tried this:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat

x = scipy.io.loadmat('test.mat')
print (x[0])
```

But it seems that it just reading the file and not putting in an array.
If I `print x[0]` I got an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mateus/Desktop/test.py", line 16, in <module>
    print (x[0])
KeyError: 0
>>>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `x = loadmat('test.mat')` instead? Can you show us also what is giving the print?

Comment: Have you saved the vector as a `.mat` file?

Comment: Yes. @MartinFevre

Comment: I tried and doesn't work. @DavidDuran

Comment: What is the print of `x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you save data in MATLAB what it saves to the file is the workspace with all variables in it. You can limit which variables are saved, but even in that case, it is saved as a workspace containing the specified variable(s).

What that means is that even if `test.mat` only has the variable "x" from MATLAB in it, when you load `test.mat` in python with `x = scipy.io.loadmat('test.mat')` you don't get just "x" as a NumPy array. If you write `print(type(x))` you will see that it is actually a dictionary.
That is why you got a `KeyError` exception. There is nothing in this dictionary with `0` as the key.

You need to specify the name of the original variable in MATLAB (also "x" in this case) to get the actual array.

That is,

```py
x = scipy.io.loadmat('test.mat')
print(x["x"])
```

prints

```
[[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]]
```

which is a 2D NumPy array representing a matrix with one row and ten columns.

---

As a final note, remember that vectors in MATLAB are "column vectors", meaning that they have dimension `1xn`. MATLAB likes to treat everything as matrices after all. In NumPy, vectors are actual 1D arrays, but since the data came from MATLAB you got a 2D array when you loaded the data in Python.